# Problem compiling C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template:

```
template<class Matrix> 
Matrix horizontal_join (const Matrix& m1, const Matrix& m2) {

ASSERT (rows (m1) == rows (m2), "unequal number of rows");
typedef typename Matrix::value_type Scalar;
Matrix r (rows (m1), nbcol (m1) + nbcol (m2));
  for (unsigned i=0; i<nbrow(m1); i++) {
      for (unsigned j=0; j<nbcol(m1); j++)
     r(i,j)= m1(i,j);
      for (unsigned j=0; j<nbcol(m2); j++)
     r(i,j+nbcol(m1))= m2(i,j);
  }
  return r;
}
```

defined in some library called "MATRDSE.m".
There is also defined a structure called "matrsdse" in a file "matrdse.hpp" which represents a dense matrix type and which has several

-constructors,e.g matrdse(int nrRows, int nrCols, const value_type *src, ByRow() )

-and methods, e.g. transpose().

I want to use the "horizontal_join" template in my main function:

```
#include <matrdse.hpp>
#include <MATRDSE.m>

typedef matrdse<double> MxPoly;    

int main{

    double v[]={1,2,1,1,3,4,2,2,5,5,5,5,-2, 1,2,3,1, -2.8,-2.4,1,.2,5.8};
matrdse<double> A(4,4,v,ByRow());
std::cout<<"A="<<endl<<A<<endl;
matrdse<double> AT(A);
AT.transpose(); std::cout<<"Transpose(A)="<<endl<<AT<<endl;
MxPoly B;
B=horizontal_join<MxPoly>(A,AT);
cout<<B<<endl;

    return 0;

 }
```

Everything works fine, until "horizontal_join" is called and returned in B.
I get the following compilation error:

```
 main.cpp:168: error: 'horizontal_join' was not declared in this scope
 main.cpp:168: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
```

I do not understand the error. As I see it I do not know how to call the template..

Thank you in advance for any suggestions,
madalina

Comment: Have you included the header for that template?

Comment: yes, I have, I have forgotten to include it in the question here.sorry

Comment: Please make the title of the question more descriptive. "use of templates" gives barely any idea of what it's about. Suggestion: "Confusing error when calling C++ template function"

Comment: May it be that the template in the header is declared inside a namespace?

Comment: Or possibly your include guards are screweed up? It certainly looks as if the compiler is not seeing the template definition.

Comment: have you tried typedef typename instead of #define?

Comment: yes,the template is defined in 2 namespaces:
namespace mmx{ 
 namespace MATRDSE { 
   //horizontal_join template definition here
 }
}

Comment: yes I also tried typedef matrdse<double> MxPoly (I get the same error)

Comment: what's with the "int main{ ... }"?  Did you mean "int main() {" ?

Comment: posting the actual code using copy & paste rather than typing in an approximation would be a good idea

Comment: Madalina, I think you should try to add the info you provided in the comments into the main question.  The proper answer will fall out very soon now :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual code?  You have the `#define` (a bad idea in itself) reversed.  It should be

```
#define MxPoly matrsde<double>
```

Comment: I used typedef matrdse< polynomial_t> MxPoly;
sorry for mistyping.

Comment: is `polynomial_t` the same as `double`?  If not, there's your problem.

Comment: yes indeed this was the error.
I need 
typedef matrdse<double> MxDouble;
 for the template used with this double matrix not a matrix of polynomials indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the combination of your preprocessor macro here (is this even right, do you have the name of the macro before the type?):

```
#define matrdse<double> MxPoly;
```

and the template instantiation here:

```
B=horizontal_join<MxPoly>(A,AT);
```

Note that the instantiation line expands in the preprocessor to this:

```
B=horizontal_join<matrdse<double>>(A,AT);
```

The template-template thing ending in `>>` is a well known compiler error that is masked here by the macro. I guess if you change the template instantiation line to this it goes away:

```
B=horizontal_join<MxPoly >(A,AT);
```

I suggest you need to use some more consistent naming, and favour typedef over macro as it will not have this problem:

```
typedef matrdse<double> MxPoly;
```

Comment: Talk about having the same answer! :-)

Comment: The macro

    #define matrdse<double> MxPoly; 

tells the preprocessor to replace the token `matrdse` with the tokens `<double> MxPoly;`

Answer (score 0):

**`#define matrdse<double> MxPoly;`**

one semicolon to much